# Where is the mapper and reducer runtime log in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

When my mapreduce job finished, i can go to the job history url and see individual reducer/mapper log in there. However, I have a lot of mappers and reducers and I need to down load them all to my local drive to analyze it. I don't know the location of those log files in hdfs. Do you know where it is?

Answer (score 2):

I presume what you need is a unix command:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <applicationId>
```

Application id is revealed during the MR application startup, e.g.

> ... 
>   15/07/13 10:52:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4 
>   15/07/13 10:52:23 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4 
>   15/07/13 10:52:23 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1424784903733_0762
>   15/07/13 10:52:24 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application **application_1424784903733_0762** 
>   ... 
>   :
>   or you can check it up in the web history web page.

What the command does is it dumps all the logs from MR processing to stout.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the userlogs are stored in the local machine only where the nodemanager service runs and where the property `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` set to.

These logs will not be save in the HDFS location. If you want to save these logs in the HDFS then you have to enable `Log Aggregation in YARN`

Check the below links for more information

[Simplifying user logs](http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/) 
[YARN Log Aggregation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/YARN+Log+Aggregation)

`Similar questions`

[Where does Hadoop store the logs of YARN applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621755/where-does-hadoop-store-the-logs-of-yarn-applications)

Answer (score 0):

The logs can be found at localhost:50070, under the utilities options