# HDP 2.3 sandbox mapreduce log

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I have System.out.printlns in my mapreduce program; The MR ran successfully, but i am not able to see the logs anywhere.
I tried with `"yarn log -applicationId ..."`, but i still don't get to see my logs.

Is there any special setting required to enable the logs? If not, what is the log file location?

Comment: Do have log aggregation enabled ?

Comment: this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621755/where-does-hadoop-store-the-logs-of-yarn-applications?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: The property yarn.log-aggregation-enable in yarn-site.xml is set to true and yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs is /hadoop/yarn/log but i dont see any files under this folder.

Comment: @ManikandanKannan, are you able to find the solution? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured log aggregation, then you will find your logs in `/tmp/logs` on HDFS . This hdfs directory is set using the property `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` (the default is /tmp/logs) .

Hence you should be able to see the users's application log directories on the namenode using the command:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/logs
```

Comment: Actually its /app-logs in the sandbox config. I see this specific app logs under /app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_....and also the yarn logs work. But from UI,i dont see both the container and the app logs. The message that i get is "Logs not available for container_..... Aggregation may not be complete, Check back later or try the nodemanager at..."....Similar message for the application logs from the UI as well

Comment: I use these URLs to access the container and the application logs......Container url: http://localhost:19888/jobhistory/logs/sandbox.hortonworks.com:45454/container_e29_1451426126284_0003_01_000001/container_e29_1451426126284_0003_01_000001/user.name=root and Job Url: http://localhost:19888/jobhistory/logs/sandbox.hortonworks.com:45454/container_e29_1451426126284_0003_01_000001/job_1451426126284_0003/user.name=root

Answer (score 3):

Port 8088 shows all the MR jobs on the cluster. Click on the MR job and click on tracking history.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the job in first few lines, it will provide you a link to track the job. You can paste that link in a browser and navigate through task level logs to see the details.

Having System.out.println in map reduce is not good practice.

Comment: I have a URL  like this http://localhost:19888/jobhistory/task/task_1450919687221_0030_m_000000....but when i click on the Logs link, i get a message saying user is not authorized.

Comment: Probably there is no jobhistory server configured. With out job history server, you will not be able to read the logs using browser.

Comment: In Ambari, i see that the history server is started